# How can I disable Windows 7's default WiFi drivers?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wifi-driver, msconfig, zeroconf

I recently installed a Netgear N600 WiFi adapter on my Windows 7 HP Desktop Computer. This adapter comes with its own drivers and a utility program for managing the adapter. I want to only use Netgear's program and disable the the Windows 7 default utility program (similar to XP's Wifi Zero). I tried ending the processes related to Windows 7's WiFi services, but the processes keep spawning back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you don't want Windows 7 to manage your Netgear wireless adapter but rather want the Netgear's utility to manage it.

The wireless adapter in Windows 7 is managed by the service WLAN Auto Config service (wlansvc). You can tell Windows 7 to not to manage this by running the command:

```
 netsh wlan set autoconfig enabled=no interface=<wireless-intf-name>
```

where '' is name of the wireless connection; in most computers this usually named as 'Wireless Network Connection'. This command tells Windows 7 not to manage your wireless adapter.

Comment: I previously tried this on administrator:command prompt, but it didn't work. I also disabled this service with msconfig, rebooted and it still respawns!.. Win7 is detecting it as not running, enables it and strats it back up, thus forcing it to be active. That's real crummy on Microsoft's part!

Comment: As @Ramhound suggested why not then try connecting with Netgear utility directly?

Comment: I do that anyway, but I would just like to do away with Win7's WLAN manager all together, amongst other undesirable features, or even do away totally with Win7 and go back to Vista SP2. It seems like just about everything that comes out with newer versions wants to take more and more control away from the user and railroad things down your throat, like it or not. I hope another class action law suit emerges against Microsoft! The status quo of the computer industry has become more of a circus, being driven by greed!

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Start, type Device Manager in the Start search box and hit
   Enter.
2. Locate Network adapters and expand it.
3. Select the wireless connection, right-click and select Properties.
4. Go to the Driver tab and click Uninstall.

Comment: I think amiregelz is on the right track, but just to expand a little... You will need the Netgear drivers installed for the adaptor to use it with their software. Remove the default Windows drivers and replace them with the Netgear ones.

Comment: I tried what @amiregelz suggested and rebooted, but the default Win7 keeps spawning back!.. Apparently Microsoft has made it so that even if you uninstall their drivers, it keeps comming back.. Frustrating!

Comment: Then try to right-click the wireless connection and click Uninstall.

Comment: did that also, it disappeared, but then it came back again! I didn't have any problems under WinVista, but Win7 is a different animal. I wish I could install Vista SP2 on this box because I was much happier with it.

Comment: Why do you want to uninstall the default WiFi driver anyway?

Comment: because the Netgear utility program is more robust. The Win 7 utility shows one bar signal strength and Netgear's is showing four bars. I'd like to do away with Win7's driver and utility all together and only rely on Netgears driver and utility programs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4348/discussion-between-frank-computer-and-amiregelz)

Comment: @FrankComputer - Just use the NetGear program to connect.  If you don't use the Windows 7 WiFi manager to connect you won't ever try to connect using the built-in WiFI manager.